# Extract URL in Sitemap With Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I need the extract links in sitemap
https://wunder.com.tr/sitemap.xml

I wrote some code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wunder = requests.get("https://wunder.com.tr/sitemap.xml")
parcala = BeautifulSoup(wunder.content,"lxml")

links = parcala.find_all("html-tag")
print(links)
```

But unable to extract.

Comment: try this, ``[x.text for x in parcala.find_all("loc")] ``

Comment: That is simply because there is no element named `html-tag`. Try simple `html` and you will get the whole html. Can you tell me specifically that what are you trying to extract from this site?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wunder = requests.get("https://wunder.com.tr/sitemap.xml")
parcala = BeautifulSoup(wunder.content, "xml")

urls_from_xml = []

loc_tags = parcala.find_all('loc')

for loc in loc_tags:
    urls_from_xml.append(loc.get_text()) 
   
print(urls_from_xml)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).